# Models aren't loaded yet/SECRET_KEY is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-models

Okay: I'm trying to use the `./manage.py makemigrations` command, but get either one of two errors.

1. If I don't comment out the third line, I get the error that a SECRET_KEY is not defined. `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.`
2. However, if I comment it out, I get the error that `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet`.

As far as I've come, I believe there might be a duplication in the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES, but I cannot find it (a previous post mentioned it). So, now I'm stuck in this loop. Did I omit something, or did I duplicate something? (The app is for a uni project, it's called "chitchatapp").
Kind Regards

> ```
> import os
> import posixpath
>
> #from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
>
> os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'chitchatapp.settings'
> application = "chitchatapp.wsgi.application"
>
> SECRET_KEY = "pi=!j5^gdg-w3*sm=#yi)3!#5$j*d$zof=5bj-e7rv$$0p#86t"
>
>
> PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir))
> PACKAGE_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
> BASE_DIR = PACKAGE_ROOT
>
> DEBUG = True
>
> DATABASES = {
>     "default": {
>         "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
>         "NAME": "dev.db",
>     }
> }
>
> ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
>
> TIME_ZONE = "UTC"
>
> LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"
>
> SITE_ID = int(os.environ.get("SITE_ID", 1))
>
> #########################################################################################
>
> USE_I18N = True
>
> USE_L10N = True
>
> USE_TZ = True
>
> #########################################################################################
>
> MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "site_media", "media")
>
> MEDIA_URL = "/site_media/media/"
>
> #########################################################################################
>
> STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "site_media", "static")
>
> STATIC_URL = "/site_media/static/"
>
> STATICFILES_DIRS = [
>     os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static", "dist"),
> ]
>
> STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
>     "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
>     "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
>     "staticfiles.finders.LegacyAppDirectoriesFinder",
>     "compressor.finders.CompressorFinder",
> ]
>
> #########################################################################################
>
> SECRET_KEY = "pi=!j5^gdg-w3*sm=#yi)3!#5$j*d$zof=5bj-e7rv$$0p#86t"
>
> #########################################################################################
>
> TEMPLATES = [
>     {
>         "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
>         "DIRS": [
>             os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "templates"),
>         ],
>         "APP_DIRS": True,
>         "OPTIONS": {
>             "debug": DEBUG,
>             "context_processors": [
>                 "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
>                 "django.core.context_processors.debug",
>                 "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
>                 "django.core.context_processors.media",
>                 "django.core.context_processors.static",
>                 "django.core.context_processors.tz",
>                 "django.core.context_processors.request",
>                 "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
>                 "account.context_processors.account",
>                 "pinax_theme_bootstrap.context_processors.theme",
>             ],
>         },
>     },
> ]
>
> TEMPLATE_LOADERS = [
>     "django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader",
>     "django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader",
> ]
>
> TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = [
>     "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
>     "django.core.context_processors.debug",
>     "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
>     "django.core.context_processors.media",
>     "django.core.context_processors.request",
>     "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
>
>     "staticfiles.context_processors.static",
>
>     "pinax.core.context_processors.pinax_settings",
>
>     "pinax.apps.account.context_processors.account",
>
>     "notification.context_processors.notification",
>     "announcements.context_processors.site_wide_announcements",
> ]
>
> #########################################################################################
>
> MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
>     "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
>     "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
>     "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
>     "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
>     "django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware",
>     "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
>     "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
>     #Postman Demo,
>     "django_openid.consumer.SessionConsumer",
>     "pinax.apps.account.middleware.LocaleMiddleware",
>     "pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware",
>     "pinax.middleware.security.HideSensistiveFieldsMiddleware",
>     "debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware",
> ]
>
> #########################################################################################
>
> ROOT_URLCONF = "chitchatapp.urls"
>
> # Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
> WSGI_APPLICATION = "chitchatapp.wsgi.application"
>
> INSTALLED_APPS = [
>     'django_admin_bootstrapped',
>     "django.contrib.admin",
>     "django.contrib.auth",
>     "django.contrib.contenttypes",  
>     "django.contrib.messages",
>     "django.contrib.sessions",
>     "django.contrib.sites",
>     #"django.contrib.staticfiles",
>
>     "django.contrib.humanize",
>     "pinax.templatetags",
>
>     # theme
>     "bootstrapform",
>     "pinax_theme_bootstrap",
>
>     # external
>     "notification", # must be first
>     "django.contrib.staticfiles",
>     "compressor",
>     "debug_toolbar",
>     "mailer",
>     "django_openid",
>     "timezones",
>     "emailconfirmation",
>     "announcements",
>     "pagination",
>     "idios",
>     "metron",
>
>     # Pinax
>     "pinax.apps.account",
>     "pinax.apps.signup_codes",
>
>     # project
>     # "about",
>     "profiles",
>     'postman',
>     "chitchatapp",
> ]
>
> #########################################################################################
>
> LOGGING = {
>     "version": 1,
>     "disable_existing_loggers": False,
>     "filters": {
>         "require_debug_false": {
>             "()": "django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse"
>         }
>     },
>     "handlers": {
>         "mail_admins": {
>             "level": "ERROR",
>             "filters": ["require_debug_false"],
>             "class": "django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler"
>         }
>     },
>     "loggers": {
>         "django.request": {
>             "handlers": ["mail_admins"],
>             "level": "ERROR",
>             "propagate": True,
>         },
>     }
> }
>
> #########################################################################################
>
> FIXTURE_DIRS = [
>     os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "fixtures"),
> ]
>
> MESSAGE_STORAGE = "django.contrib.messages.storage.session.SessionStorage"
>
> EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend"
>
> ACCOUNT_OPEN_SIGNUP = True
> ACCOUNT_EMAIL_UNIQUE = True
> ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_REQUIRED = False
> ACCOUNT_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "home"
> ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "home"
> ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 2
> ACCOUNT_USE_AUTH_AUTHENTICATE = True
>
> AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
>     "account.auth_backends.UsernameAuthenticationBackend",
> ]
> ```

Comment: To get you started, `from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application` and the two lines below it do not belong in your settings file, they only go in your wsgi file. The wsgi module is for apache whereas makemigrations is command line which means your settings file needs to remain agnostic. Can you provide the full error output for the second message (after removing all 3 lines)?

Comment: Also, `SECRET_KEY` appears twice in your settings file which is probably not a problem but is redundant. AND CHANGE YOUR SECRET KEY BECAUSE YOU JUST POSTED IT, it should be secret.

Comment: @Dotcomly `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.` This is the output in Terminal after the lines between `import posixpath`and `secretkey` are taken out. EDIT: Here's a longer version `File "/Users/Home/Desktop/pinax-chitchat/chitchat/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.`

Comment: Surething, the Secretkey appears twice because of my attempt to remove the error. I'll generate a new secret key ASAP.

Comment: My best guess is the order of `INSTALLED_APPS`. Try putting all the `django.contrib.*` apps first (and `notification` as it says `# must be first`) then start removing apps one by one and see if the error goes away so you can identify the app causing trouble. If you can resolve it to an app let me know and we can continue from there. If not, start doing the same thing to middleware.

Comment: I'll get back to you as soon as I'm done. Regardless of the outcome

Comment: I'm not sure why you're setting the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in the settings file. There are several ways to do this, e.g. putting in the manage.py, or by using envdir. Maybe this is related to your problem?

Comment: I took it out as Dotcomly advised. Still not working though

Comment: okay, so I figured it out yesterday. I changed the installed_apps' and middleware_classes' order. Still didnt work.. so I deactivated my Venv, restarted my laptop, activated my venv and ran all the migrations and it worked. It probably was due to me changing so much that Django cached most of it. Thanks for all the help @Dotcomly